# Java JLabel ignores alpha value of foreground color when rendering HTML

Tags: java, html, jlabel, alpha

When I use a JLabel with a foreground color which has an alpha value, like so:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel( "This is non HTML text with correct alpha color" );
label.setForeground( new Color( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.5f) );
```

the label is displayed correctly with 0.5-alpha, so 50% gray.

But when I change the text to HTML (to have more control over the text rendering), like so:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel( "<html><p>This is HTML text with incorrect alpha color</p></html>" );
label.setForeground( new Color( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.5f) );
```

Then the label is 100% white. It seems, while rendering HTML, the alpha value of the foreground color is just being ignored.

I'm using Java 1.6.0_26 (32bit) under Windows 7 64 Bit.

Is this a bug or a known limitation, or do I anything wrong here?

Comment: does opacity (alpha) really works on html code? Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531494/fading-a-jlabel-that-contains-html

Comment: I think you are right, I only know alpha transparency with CSS, not with "plain" HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot mix HTML code and setForeground styling together.

See [JLabel html text ignores setFont](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7265178/jlabel-html-text-ignores-setfont?rq=1) and How to use JLabels([1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html)) tutorial from oracle.

Just use either HTML or JLabel styling.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for your answer. As a side note, if I cannot mix it, it should ignore the foreground color altogether, not just the alpha part. I mean, I can make the HTML text green with ".setForeground( Color.GREEN );", to the setForeground-Styling has still an effect on the HTML rendering

Answer (score 1):

To give a possible answer to my own question, I just found a way to do alpha transparency with HTML-rendering. Just override the "paintComponent" Method of JLabel and use an AlphaComposite with the given Graphics2D instance:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent( Graphics g )
{
    Composite alphaComposite = AlphaComposite.getInstance( AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.5f );

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g.create();
    g2d.setComposite( alphaComposite );

    super.paintComponent( g2d );
}
```