# JLabel shifts the text vertically down while displaying HTML

Tags: java, html, swing, rendering, jlabel

I would like to understand why a JLabel, rendering HTML, shifts the vertical position of it's output text, whereas a JLabel which renders non-HTML, does not.

- **Java version used**: 1.6.0_37
- **Swing Look and Feel used**: Windows ("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel")
- **OS**: Windows 7 64 Bit

I did not put a SSCCE together since the code is really trivial. But if it helps please say so.

I rather give an examples using an images displaying the behavior:

[image: Example of JLabel, rendering plain text and HTML]

I put a JPanel as the container around the JLabel to visualize the label's bounds. After setting the font and text for the JLabel, the

```
jLabel.getPreferredSize()
```

method returns the bounds of the rendered plain text or HTML (and this is the exact size I set for the surrounding JPanel). You can clearly see, that, if rendering HTML, the whole text is shifted a small amount down.

I would like to know why this happens and what I can do to correct the placement.

One workaround would be to translate the Graphics2D on which to render the text, to compensate the vertical shift, like this:

```
g2d.translate( 0, -20 );
```

But I don't know the correct y value in relation to the font metrics (e.g. font size). Anyway, this workaround also feels "wrong".

I really appreciate your answers, thanks a lot!

Comment: Please add your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) at least than we dont have to write the code from scratch and you will get help even faster.

Comment: I was just about writing the SSCCE when I saw your good answer down below :)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that if we set the `Font` (family,size etc) for the HTML `JLabel` using `setFont(..)` the font is not rendered to the correct metrics of `JLabel`.

Here is an example I made to demonstrate (Both `JLabel`s shown are using HTML):

[image]

A simple work around is to the the font size, family etc in HTML too.

As we can see the *cyan* HTML `JLabel` used `setFont(..)` (and was incorrectly rendered) while the *green* HTML `JLabel` used HTML to set the font and was rendered correctly:

```
JLabel labelHtml2 = new JLabel("<html><font size=10 family='Calibri'>" + text + "</font></html>");
```

**Test.java:**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static Font font = new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 38);

    public Test() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();

                }
                new Test();
            }
        });
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        String text = "Hello world";

        //this label will not render correctly due to setting font via setFont(..)
        JLabel labelHtml1 = new JLabel("<html>" + text + "</html>");
        labelHtml1.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        labelHtml1.setOpaque(true);//so background will be painted
        labelHtml1.setFont(font);

        //this label will render correcty font is set via html
        JLabel labelHtml2 = new JLabel("<html><font size=10 family='Calibri'>" + text + "</font></html>");
        labelHtml2.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        labelHtml2.setOpaque(true);
        //labelHtml2.setFont(font);

        frame.add(labelHtml1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(labelHtml2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: These are really good thoughts. It may also be related to ["Java JLabel ignores alpha value of foreground color when rendering HTML"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12663268/java-jlabel-ignores-alpha-value-of-foreground-color-when-rendering-html/12665187). We can assume that JLabel partly "ignores" it's font settings as well as it's color (with transparency) due to the fact, that it is controlled by the HTML code itself.

Comment: I just noticed that this seems to happen for the font "Calibri", but not for "Tahoma". Settings "Tahoma" via `jLabel.setFont(...)` does not result in translated HTML output (in which case you do not have to use the `<font...>...</font>` tag).

Comment: @It'sLeto very interesting indeed must be a bug. Maybe think about reporting it to Oracle: http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/

Comment: Hey @David, I think there is an error in your code - the lower "Hello World" is NOT the font "Calibri", although you defined it via the `<font..>` HTML tag. It is hard to spot because "Hello World" looks very similar in "Tahoma". If you change the text including a comma, you can see the difference. So the question remains - how to vertically position the text with font "Calibri" correctly?